# Public Site is not displaying dashboard

Tags: javascript, dashboard

I displayed visualforce page as public site. But as soon as I added a dashboard onto the visualforce page using the following code....

**APEX**

```
    public String getDashboardHtml(){
    PageReference dbPage = new      
    PageReference('https://na15.salesforce.com/01Zi00000006AEr');
    Blob pageBlob = dbPage.getContent();
    return pageBlob.toString();
}
```

**VF**

```
 <script>
  document.getElementById('mainArea').innerHTML = '{!dashboardHtml}';
 </script>
```

...I get  *Authorization Required 
You must first log in or register before accessing this page. 
If you have forgotten your password, click Forgot Password to reset it*

But If I delete the script from vf then everything is ok.

I have the correct settings to expose all the desired custom objects. How do I expose the  dashboard?

Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboards must be viewed through authentication. Public site do not have authentication and so will not be able to access dashboard.

Here is workaround you can try: you could make a site that logs in, uses the metadata API to get the dashboard data, and then caches it. This site would then not require authentication. However, you will need lot of coding.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the analytics API http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/salesforce_analytics_rest_api.pdf

Comment: I tried that. I'm using a developer edition. Can I transfer a dashboard to a different folder from the personal folder?

Comment: Sure you can. First you need to create a dashboard folder though